# python pandas でのデータ処理について

Tags: python, pandas

こんにちは。python pandas 超初学者の文系の者です。色々と調べてはみたのですが、どうすれば良いか分からずに困り果てています。お力添えをお願いいたします。

あるエクセルデータを読み込み、以下のようなグラフの作成をしているのですが、x軸は範囲を限定し、さらに、y軸はデータが０から始まるように移動させたいのです。具体的に言うと、x軸は0.05から0,25まで、y軸は0から始まり、データも0から始まるようにしたいのです。

このグラフを描画するところまではなんとかたどり着きましたが、ここからどうしていいかさっぱりわかりません。

元のエクセルデータ自体をいじらないと不可能でしょうか？
ソースコードを以下に載せておきます。

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

line_min=4
line_max=384

data=xlrd.open_workbook('702_1.xls')

Sheet2=data.sheet_by_index(1)

print Sheet2.ncols

print data.sheet_names()

strain=Sheet2.col_values(1,start_rowx=line_min,end_rowx=line_max)
force=Sheet2.col_values(14,start_rowx=line_min,end_rowx=line_max)

figure()
plot(strain,force,'b')
show()
```

[image: data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これでどうですか（force= 以下を書き換え）

```
force = np.array(Sheet2.col_values(14, start_rowx=line_min, end_rowx=line_max))
force -= np.min(force)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(strain, force, 'b')
ax.set_xlim(0.05, 0.25)
plt.show()
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。
force以下を書き換えたのですが、y軸が１ぐらいから始まり、ものすごく角度の小さいグラフが表示されました。
plt.show()
の部分を

figure()
plot(strain,force,'b')
show()

とすると、角度の小さいグラフ（x軸が0.25までのもの）と、角度の大きい、０点から始まるグラフ（x軸は1.6までだが、y軸は０から始まっている）の２つが描画されてしまいます。何が問題なのでしょうか…

Comment: >> y軸が１ぐらいから始まり
上の図を見る限りですが, データはx=0.0の時にy=1, x=0.05の時にy=2 くらいになっているように思います. したがって, データの最小値を0に揃えるようにy軸のデータ全体から約1を引いた場合, x=0.05の時にはy=1程度になるのではないでしょうか.（set_xlim(0.00, 0.25) とすれば, データはx=0のときy=0になっていると思います）

Comment: >> ものすごく角度の小さいグラフが表示されました
x軸と同様, y軸も
`ax.set_ylim(0, なんらかの数字)`
とすれば, 見やすくはなると思います.

Comment: >> plt.show() の部分を figure() plot(strain,force,'b') show() とすると: 

そもそもですが、
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
`from pylab import *`
は片方だけで大丈夫です. figure() とfig, ax = plt.subplots() は機能的には同等の関数ですので, どちらか片方のモジュールだけを使えば大丈夫です.

figure() show()のグラフの角度が適当なのは, ax.set_xlim()がplt.subplots()の方のグラフにしか効いていなからだと思います.

Comment: ax.set_ylim(0.82,5)のコードを入れ、余計なコードを消しました。本当にありがとうございました。